# Create index with geoshape property mapping

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using Elasticsearch's NEST client library to create an index for a specific type.

The type contains three `string` properties plus one to hold a `geo_shape` type (for use with an `envelope` shape, specifically).

The thing is, the generated request fails to parse in ES:

```
{
   "error": "MapperParsingException[mapping [layer]]; nested: MapperParsingException[No handler for type [point] declared on field [boundingBox]]; ",
   "status": 400
}
```

The request builded by NEST that produced this error message is:

```
POST /metadata
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "layer": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
        "namespace": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "abstract": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "boundingBox": {
          "type": "point",
          "tree": "geohash",
          "tree_levels": 2,
          "distance_error_pct": 0.025
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've found that the only thing keeping this request from success is the `type` declaration for the `boundingBox` property, which should have a value of `geo_shape` rather than `point`.

Here the C# code used to perform the call:

```
ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(settings);

IIndicesOperationResponse response = client.CreateIndex(c => c
    .Index("metadata")
    .NumberOfShards(1)
    .NumberOfReplicas(0)
    .AddMapping<ESLayer>(m => m
        .Type("layer")
        .AllField(a => a.Enabled(false))
        .Properties(p => p
        .String(x => x.Name(n => n.Namespace))
        .String(x => x.Name(n => n.Name))
        .String(x => x.Name(n => n.Abstract))
        .GeoShape(x => x
            .Name(n => n.BoundingBox)
            .Tree(GeoTree.Geohash)
            .TreeLevels(2)
            .DistanceErrorPercentage(0.025)))));
```

And the `ESLayer` class:

```
private class ESLayer
{
    public string Namespace { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Abstract { get; set; }

    public EnvelopeGeoShape BoundingBox { get; set; }
}
```

Note that I'm using the `EnvelopeGeoShape` class that comes with NEST to represent the bounding box property.

Elasticsearch version: 1.3.1

NEST version: 1.0.2

Any clue on what I might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug for sure; nice catch.  I just opened issue [#925](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/925) for this and pushed a fix.  It'll be included in the next release (1.1.0) which we plan on getting out very soon.  In the mean time, you can grab the NuGet package from our CI builds here:  https://www.myget.org/gallery/elasticsearch-net.

Comment: Thanks @Greg, it's good to hear that! I'm going to switch to the next version as soon as it's released. In the meantime, I would like to test the nightly build, but myget seems to be down right now. Any other source for the package?

Comment: Myget seems to be working fine, for me at least.  The only other option would be to clone the GitHub repo and compile the solution.

Comment: I've tried compiling the source and it worked. Also tried to access myget today, and its working for me now. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is no type for point in ES. You should use 'geo_point' or 'geo_shape' depending on your requirement.

see:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html

also:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html

edit: the mapping options you are using are meant for geo_shape type

Comment: Thanks, I realized that. But I'm not writing the request to ES by hand, but through the NEST library. My question is more about the .NET code used to create the index, if it's missing something, or perhaps I'm facing a NEST bug.